# Chain rule for maximal correlation

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics, it.information-theory

Let a pair of random variables $(X,Y)$ be defined over finite alphabet $\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}$ with joint distribution $P_{XY}$. The maximal correlation $\rho(X;Y)$ between $X$ and $Y$ is defined as 
$$\rho(X;Y):=\max_{f,g}\mathbb{E}[f(X)g(Y)],$$ where the maximization is taken over real-valued functions $f$ and $g$ such that $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\mathbb{E}[g(Y)]=0$ and $\mathbb{E}[f^2(X)]=\mathbb{E}[g^2(Y)]=1$. A single-function characterization of maximal correlation correlation was given by by Renyi as follows:
$$\rho^2(X;Y)=\max_{f}\mathbb{E}[(\mathbb{E}[f(X)|Y])^2],$$ where $f$ satisfies the above conditions as well. One can easily see that for any arbitrary random variables $X$ and $Y$, $0\leq\rho(X;Y)\leq 1$ where 0 is achieved iff $X$ and $Y$ are independent and 1 is achieved iff there exists a pair of functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(X)=g(Y)$ almost surely.

Suppose $X, Y$ and $Z$ satisfy the Markov condition $X\to Y\to Z$ (that is, $P_{XYZ}(x, y, z)=P_X(x)P_{Y|X}(y|x)P_{Z|Y}(z|y)$). Then it can be easily shown that (see for example page 4 of [this](https://statistics.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/2002-25.pdf))
$$\rho((X,Y); Z)=\rho(Y;Z).$$

I am interested to find a closed form expression for 
$$\rho((X,Y);Z)-\rho(X;Z),$$ in general case for any $X, Y$ and $Z$. From above, this has to reduce to $\rho(Y;Z)-\rho(X;Z)$ when $X\to Y\to Z$.

I am in particular interested to prove a chain-rule-like statement for maximal correlation (like chain rule for mutual information and entropy in information theory).

Any ideas and thoughts on how to (dis)prove this? Or any reference talking about a similar problem?

Comment: Do you have a definition of $\rho(Y; Z|X)$ other than the difference $\rho((X, Y); Z)-\rho(X;Z)$? Or do you want an alternative expression of this difference? And if you do not have an alternative expression of $\rho(Y; Z|X)$, what is here to prove or disprove?

Comment: I dont have any definition for the conditional maximal correlation. I want to find an expression for $\rho((X,Y); Z)$ in terms of $\rho(X;Z)$ and another term. I then "define" that term as the conditional maximal correlation. Is it clear now?

Comment: It appears more certain to me now that you want an alternative expression for the difference $\rho((X,Y);Z)−\rho(X;Z)$. It is still unclear what you wanted to prove or disprove.

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks Iosif for your comments.